# Error with befriending a function in a namespace in C++

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, friend-function

I've tried to befriend a function in a namespace but I don't know why there is an error:

> Error C2653 'a': is not a class or namespace name

I've tried multiple times and I don't think it's a mistake on my part but take a look:

```
class plpl
{
private:
    int m;
public:
    plpl()
        : m(3) {}

    friend void a::abc();
};

namespace a {
    void abc();
    void abc()
    {
        plpl p;
        std::cout << p.m << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I use Visual Studio 2019. I don't know what to do, please help.

Comment: Declare the namespace before you reference it, e.g. with `namespace a {}`. Also put the declaration of `void abc();` there as well. It is pointless to forward-declare a function immediately before defining it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments, you need to forward declare the namespace `a` and the function `abc`, as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace a {
    void abc();
}

class plpl {
private:
    int m;
public:
    plpl() : m(3) {}

    friend void a::abc();
};

namespace a {
    void abc() {
        plpl p;
        std::cout << p.m << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I already figured how to fix it from the comment but thank you :)

Comment: I figured it might help to see it. Glad you were able to get a solution to your problem!